# as expected a)a before a[a token Error in declaring array as a shared variable in the pragma parallel directive

Tags: c, openmp

- I have been trying to parallelize computing the sum value of series using a certain number of terms to the processors using block allocation.
- In this program, I am generating arithmetic series and want to pass array as a shared variable in the pragma parallel directive.
- but error coming in line `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(comm_sz, number, BLOCK_LOW, BLOCK_HIGH, a[n], first, difference, global_sum1)` providing the error below
  `expected a)a before a[a token`
- I am new to OPENMP-C. I have written th code below and facing the error above. -I researched in google but unable to find the solution. 
  Kindly help me how to declare array as shared variable in pragma parallel directive. I am attaching the code below

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int rank, comm_sz;
  int number, i, first, difference, global_sum1, global_sum, nprocs, step, local_sum1, local_n;
  int* a;
  int BLOCK_LOW, BLOCK_HIGH;
  double t0, t1;

  comm_sz = atoi(argv[1]);
  first = atoi(argv[2]);
 difference  = atoi(argv[3]);
  number = atoi(argv[4]);
  omp_set_num_threads (comm_sz);
  rank = omp_get_thread_num();
  a = (int*) malloc (n*sizeof(int));
  printf("comm_sz=%d, first=%d, difference=%d, number of terms=%d\n",comm_sz, first, difference, number);

 for(i=1; i <= number; i++){
  a[i-1] = first + (i-1)*difference;
  printf("a[%d]=%d\n",i-1,a[i]);
  }

  for(i=0; i < number; i++){
  printf("a[%d]=%d\n",i,a[i]);}


  t0 = omp_get_wtime();

  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(comm_sz, number, BLOCK_LOW, BLOCK_HIGH, a[n], first, difference, global_sum1)
  {
    BLOCK_LOW = (rank * number)/comm_sz;
    BLOCK_HIGH = ((rank+1) * number)/comm_sz;

  #pragma omp parallel while private(i, local_sum1)
    //int local_sum1 = 0;
    i=BLOCK_LOW;
    while( i < BLOCK_HIGH )
    { 
      printf("%d, %d\n",BLOCK_LOW,BLOCK_HIGH);
      local_sum1 = local_sum1 + a[i];
      i++;
    }
    //global_sum1 = global_sum1 + local_sum1;

    #pragma omp while reduction(+:global_sum1)
    i=0;
    for (i < comm_sz) {
      global_sum1 = global_sum1 + local_sum1;
      i++;
    }
  }

  step = 2*first + (n-1)*difference;
    sum = 0.5*n*step;
     printf("sum is %d\n", global_sum );

  t1 = omp_get_wtime();
  printf("Estimate of pi: %7.5f\n", global_sum1);
  printf("Time: %7.2f\n", t1-t0);
}
```

Comment: Is the above truly the OpenMP directive you used? If so, no wonder it fails as `num_thread()` only expects **one single integer** value or variable that can be evaluated while encountering the directive at run time. I admit the error isn't very explicit though (assuming you copied the actual directive)

Comment: @Gilles thanks for your reply...it worked...can you help me with this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884606/error-in-computing-output-values-due-to-non-synchronization-of-mpi-send-and-mpi

Comment: This code wouldn't compile even if you took out the OpenMP directives! Is this homework?